# What is the syntax of the Dockerfile EXPOSE Command?

Tags: docker

Reading the docker documentation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose the expose command syntax is described as:

```
EXPOSE <port> [<port>/<protocol>...]
```

To me, this indicates that I can use it like:

```
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8080 8081/tcp 8082/udp
```

but not

```
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
```

The examples they give contradict this:

```
EXPOSE 80/udp
```

and to expose the same port on different protocols they suggest using two lines:

```
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 80/udp
```

What does the syntax description actually mean?
Does `EXPOSE 8080 8081` expose two ports?
Is `EXPOSE 80/tcp 80/udp` illegal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is actually something like

```
"EXPOSE ", { p };
```

where

```
p = port, [ "/", proto ], " ";
```

(in EBNF)

> Does `EXPOSE 8080 8081` expose two ports?

Yes

> Is `EXPOSE 80/tcp 80/udp` illegal?

No

Comment: Thanks, that makes a good deal more sense -- where could I have found this out myself? (I did look)

Comment: @tgdavies For example https://github.com/camdencheek/tree-sitter-dockerfile/blob/main/src/grammar.json#L245

Comment: Or maybe this is more authoritative: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/3330fc2e9320e46d345132f07ec0ea7b42029e47/builder/dockerfile/dispatchers.go#L505